# Permutar subvectores dado un vector utilizando R

Tags: r

Tengo un vector columna de ¨n¨ componentes como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
c(1,3,8,10,23,78,5,15,47,1,8,51)
```

¿De qué forma puedo obtener con `R` un vector en el que para cada seis elementos se aplique una permutación?.

Por ejemplo una posible primera permutación con los primeros seis elementos es `(8,1,78,3,10,23)` y otra permutación tentativa para los siguientes seis elementos `(47,8,15,1,51,5)`
de esta manera el vector columna final sería c(8,1,78,3,10,23,47,8,15,1,51,5).
Existe en R, alguna función como SAMPLE que hága esta rutina, o algunas lineas de código para esta rutina son bienvenidas.

Gracias.

Comment: Siempre es bueno colocar algo más de lo que has intentado!

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion es llevar a data frames y usar la function group_by del paquete dplyr (que a su vez viene en tidyverse).

Los pasos serian principalmente crear una partición de acuerdo al # de elemento y la cantidad de grupos, luego usar la function `group_by` para agrupar por partición y realizar el calculo la nueva variable (permutacion) usando sample.

```r
v <- c(1, 3, 8, 10, 23, 78, 5, 15, 47, 1, 8, 51)
n_para_permutar <- 4

library(tidyverse)

d <- data_frame(v)
d
#> # A tibble: 12 x 1
#>        v
#>    <dbl>
#>  1    1.
#>  2    3.
#>  3    8.
#>  4   10.
#>  5   23.
#>  6   78.
#>  7    5.
#>  8   15.
#>  9   47.
#> 10    1.
#> 11    8.
#> 12   51.

# creamos el numero de fila
d <- mutate(d, fila = row_number())
d
#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>        v  fila
#>    <dbl> <int>
#>  1    1.     1
#>  2    3.     2
#>  3    8.     3
#>  4   10.     4
#>  5   23.     5
#>  6   78.     6
#>  7    5.     7
#>  8   15.     8
#>  9   47.     9
#> 10    1.    10
#> 11    8.    11
#> 12   51.    12

# creamos la particion
d <- mutate(d, particion = ceiling(fila/n_para_permutar))
d
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>        v  fila particion
#>    <dbl> <int>     <dbl>
#>  1    1.     1        1.
#>  2    3.     2        1.
#>  3    8.     3        1.
#>  4   10.     4        1.
#>  5   23.     5        2.
#>  6   78.     6        2.
#>  7    5.     7        2.
#>  8   15.     8        2.
#>  9   47.     9        3.
#> 10    1.    10        3.
#> 11    8.    11        3.
#> 12   51.    12        3.

# agrupamos
d <- group_by(d, particion)
d
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#> # Groups:   particion [3]
#>        v  fila particion
#>    <dbl> <int>     <dbl>
#>  1    1.     1        1.
#>  2    3.     2        1.
#>  3    8.     3        1.
#>  4   10.     4        1.
#>  5   23.     5        2.
#>  6   78.     6        2.
#>  7    5.     7        2.
#>  8   15.     8        2.
#>  9   47.     9        3.
#> 10    1.    10        3.
#> 11    8.    11        3.
#> 12   51.    12        3.

# creamos los valores de acuerdo a la permutacion
d <- mutate(d, v2 = sample(v))
d
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   particion [3]
#>        v  fila particion    v2
#>    <dbl> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1    1.     1        1.   10.
#>  2    3.     2        1.    1.
#>  3    8.     3        1.    3.
#>  4   10.     4        1.    8.
#>  5   23.     5        2.   23.
#>  6   78.     6        2.   15.
#>  7    5.     7        2.    5.
#>  8   15.     8        2.   78.
#>  9   47.     9        3.   47.
#> 10    1.    10        3.   51.
#> 11    8.    11        3.    8.
#> 12   51.    12        3.    1.

# extramos el vector
v2 <- pull(d, v2)
v2
#>  [1] 10  1  3  8 23 15  5 78 47 51  8  1
```

En resumen y en menos lineas:

```r
v <- c(1,3,8,10,23,78,5,15,47,1,8,51)
n_para_permutar <- 4

library(tidyverse)

data_frame(v) %>%
    mutate(fila = row_number()) %>% # creamos el numero de fila
    mutate(particion =  ceiling(fila/n_para_permutar)) %>% # creamos la particion
    group_by(particion) %>%  # agrupamos
    mutate(v2 = sample(v)) %>% # creamos los valores de acuerdo a la permutacion
    pull(v2)
#>  [1]  8  3 10  1 15 78 23  5  8 51 47  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con `sample()` tal como lo habías pensado, solo que debieras hacerlo en dos partes, la primera para los elementos 1 al 6 y la segunda para los del 7 al 12.

```
mi_vector <- c(1,3,8,10,23,78,5,15,47,1,8,51)
c(sample(mi_vector[1:6]), sample(mi_vector[7:12]))
```

Hacemos una operación de acceso por índice del vector usando los "corchetes" (`[]`) e indicando un vector de elementos, primero `1:6` -> `c(1,2,3,4,5,6)` y luego `7:12` -> `c(7,8,9,10,11,12)`. Con cada uno de los subvectores corremos `sample()` y por último concatenamos los dos subvectores con `c()`

Ahora bien, para una solución más genérica, siempre hablando de vectores como entrada y usando la funcionalidad base, podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
mi_vector <- c(1,3,8,10,23,78,5,15,47,1,8,51)
n <- 6
unlist(lapply(seq(1,length(mi_vector),n),FUN=function(x) {sample(mi_vector[x:(x+n-1)])}))
```

La lógica es la misma que explique antes, solo que la aplicamos mediante `lapply()` de forma dinámica a `mi_vector` de a grupos de `n` valores. Es fundamental que el vector sea múltiplo de `n`.